# Module registration when using typescript with System.js

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript and I want the compiled output to be concatenated to a single file. I'm using SystemJs module. But the output changes if I have an 'import' statement in the script files. Let's say my only source file looks like this

```
export class SimpleGame{
    constructor(){
        console.log('simple game');
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    var game = new SimpleGame();
}
```

then the output is

```
var SimpleGame = (function () {
    function SimpleGame() {
        console.log('simple game');
    }
    return SimpleGame;
}());
window.onload = function () {
    var game = new SimpleGame();
};
```

which is good, but let's say I have another file called `logic.ts` and I used a statement

`import { Logic } from './logic';`

the output would look like this

```
System.register("logic", [], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    var Logic;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            Logic = (function () {
                function Logic() {
                }
                return Logic;
            }());
            exports_1("Logic", Logic);
        }
    };
});
System.register("game", [], function (exports_2, context_2) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_2 && context_2.id;
    var SimpleGame;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            SimpleGame = (function () {
                function SimpleGame() {
                    console.log('simple game');
                }
                return SimpleGame;
            }());
            window.onload = function () {
                var game = new SimpleGame();
            };
        }
    };
});
//# sourceMappingURL=game.js.map
```

And the code `window.onload will not execute`

Anyone has any idea on how to get the code to execute?

Comment: What you have said is not accurate on both counts. 1: The first piece of code is wrapped in a `register` call. 2: the `window.onload` code does execute, when the module is imported.

Comment: Any file containing a top level `import` or `export` is a module and will be wrapped in a `register` call by TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you have imported/exported something into your file it effectively becomes module. And in order its code to be run you must instruct your loader (system.js) to load it. This can be done on your web page using the snippet similar to the one below:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) 
    {//Entry point of the application.
        System.import('SimpleGame').catch(function(e)
        {
            console.error(e);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Of course I assume that your have properly initialised your system.js using its [config](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md) method, and it knows where to look for your `SimpleGame` module.

Comment: Did you mean **As soon as you have imported _or_ exported"**?

Comment: While this solved my problem, it's not satisfactory. The fact that compiler behavior changed with a statement is very disturbing. I'd prefer using CommonJs modules but Typescript does not support concatenation for that.